# Ruby one line if statement with exception handling

Tags: ruby, exception, ternary-operator

I cannot seem to find a way to do this.
All I want to do is try the first statement, if it is blank or null (at any stage) then return the other one. For instance

```
a.b.c.blank? ? a.b.c : 'Fill here'
```

This is causing me `nil:NillClass` exception. Is there a way to fix this in a simple one liner way?

Comment: you can take a look at [`andand`](https://github.com/raganwald/andand)..

Comment: If you found at least one of the answers helpful, please consider selecting the one you liked best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `active_support` available, you can use [`Object#try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try):

```
a.try(:b).try(:c) or 'Fill here'
```

If you don't have that, it's pretty easy to monkey-patch `Object` to add one. Here's the code in `active_support`, just put it some where before you are using `try` method.

```
class Object
  def try(*a, &b)
    if a.empty? && block_given?
      yield self
    else
      public_send(*a, &b) if respond_to?(a.first)
    end
  end
end
```

After that, you can use it:

```
a = nil
a.try(:b).try(:c).try(:nil?)    #=> true

b = 1
b.try(:+, 2)    #=> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not `nil:NilClass` exception thrown by default.

`a` or `b` or `c` may be nil, so for a one line statement you can do:

```
# require this to use present?, not needed with rails
require 'active_support/all'

a.present? ? (a.b.present? ? (a.b.c.present? ? a.b.c : 'Fill here') : 'Fill here') : 'Fill here'
```

(And this is ternary expression, not exactly an if statement)

But this is ugly, although you can remove parts of the expression if you are sure that `a` or `a.b` is never `nil`.

I used `present?` over `blank?` to keep the same order as your expression. The ternary operator evaluates the first expression if the condition is true, so this may be your error.

Comment: That's a nested way. What if I have something that is really deep?

Comment: Don't do it in one line then, or check before if your object is not `nil`. The base condition is just `var.present? ? var : 'default value'`

Answer (score 0):

I would require the ActiveSupport package that allow the use of `presence` do something like this:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'
a.presence && a.b.presence && a.b.c.presence || 'Fill here'
```

See: http://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence

Comment: I don't know Rails, but have a suspicion that you could do something like this: `[a,b,c,..].reduce(?) { |e| (e ||= ?) ... }`.  Just food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Ruby 2.3.0** (released 2015-12-25), this can be achieved using the `save navigation operator`, which is similar to Groovy's and Kotlin's null safe `?`:

> new method call syntax, `object&.foo', method foo is called on`object' if it is not nil.

```
# a as object { b: { c: 'foobar' } }
a&.b&.c&.empty? ? 'Fill here' : a.b.c #=> 'foobar'
nil&.b&.c&.empty? ? 'Fill here' : a.b.c #=> 'Fill here'
```

Safe calls return `nil` when they're called upon nil objects. This is why the second case in the above example evaluates to `nil` and thus `false`.

source: [NEWS for Ruby 2.3.0 (Feature #11537)](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/NEWS-2_3_0.html)
see also: [What is the difference between `try` and `&.` (safe navigation operator) in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45825498/10289238)