# What is the difference between `try` and `&.` (safe navigation operator) in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, nomethoderror, grape-api

Here is my code:

```
class Order < Grape::Entity
  expose :id { |order, options| order.id.obfuscate }
  expose :time_left_to_review do |order, options|
    byebug
    order&.time_left_to_review # ERROR
  end
  expose :created_at { |order, options| order.last_transition.created_at }
end

# NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `time_left_to_review' for #<Order:0x007f83b9efc970>
```

I thought `&.` is a shortcut for `.try` but I guess I was wrong. May someone point me to the right direction regarding what I am missing?

I feel like it's not ruby related. Grape maybe? Though I don't get how it could be.

Comment: They are not the same, you can read more about the difference [here](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

`&.` works like `#try!`, not `#try`.

And here is description of `#try!` (from [documentation](http://devdocs.io/rails%7E5.1/object#method-i-try-21)):

> Same as #try, but will raise a NoMethodError exception if the receiving is not nil and does not implemented the tried method.

So, `&.` saves you from calling a method on `nil`, but if the object is present it will try to call the method as usual, including raising `NoMethodError` if the method is not implemented.

`#try`, on the other hand, saves you from calling a method on `nil` *and* calling a method that is not implemented. It will return `nil` in either case, and never raise `NoMethodError`.

The quote is from Rails Documentation, and so it's important to emphasize that Ruby does not provide `#try`; it's provided by Rails, or more accurately ActiveSupport. The [safe navigation operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator) (`&.`) however, is a language feature presented in Ruby 2.3.0.

Comment: "So basically it saves you from calling a method on nil" - what does the "it" in this sentence refer to?

Comment: @Jason: "it" is the safe navigation operator or try!.

Answer (score 20):

The `try` method ignores a lot of things, it just gives it a shot and calls it a day if things don't work out.

The `&` conditional navigation option will *only* block calls on `nil` objects. Anything else is considered to be valid and will proceed with full consequences, exceptions included.

Answer (score 20):

I am arriving to the party a bit late here, the other answers have covered how it works, but I wanted to add something that the other answers have not covered.

Your question asks What is the difference between `try` and `&.` in **Ruby**. Ruby being the key word here.

The biggest difference is that `try` doesn't exist in Ruby, it is a method provided by Rails. you can see this or yourself if you do something like this in the rails console:

```
[1, 2, 3].try(:join, '-')
#=> "1-2-3"
```

However if you do the same thing in the irb console, you will get:

```
[1, 2, 3].try(:join, '-')
NoMethodError: undefined method `try' for [1, 2, 3]:Array
```

The `&.` is part of the Ruby standard library, and is therefore available in any Ruby project, not just Rails.

Comment: So in case your code might be running in pure Ruby, you should do `foo.try(:try, ...)` to be on the safe side.

Comment: Sorry @mwfearnley but I don't understand your comment. If the code is in pure Ruby (i.e outside of Rails or not using `ActiveSupport`) then what's the point of doing `foo.try(:try...)` if `foo.try`  will raise a `NoMethodError` ?

Comment: @gasc Looking back at my comment now, I have to conclude it was a joke, based on the fact that the advice was "obviously" bad..  Of course, if you are almost certain that `foo.try(:try...)` will fail, then you should do `foo.try(:try, :try...)` to be extra safe..

Comment: ...and I ruined the joke =(

My bad @mwfearnley

Comment: In pure Ruby, `foo` or `!foo`, there is no `#try`

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the above answers, I am adding some examples.[1](https://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/)

```rb
account = Account.new(owner: Object.new)

account.try(:owner).try(:address)
# => nil

account&.owner&.address
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `address' for #<Object:0x00559996b5bde8>`

account.try!(:owner).try!(:address)
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `address' for #<Object:0x00559996b5bde8>`
```

As we can see, `try` doesn't check if the receiver responds to the given method or not. Whereas `try!` and `&.` behaves the same. If the receiver responds to the `address` method, all of them will return the same result. I prefer using `&.` as it looks more cleaner.

For more information on The Safe Navigation Operator (&.), I have found this blog really helpful https://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/

Comment: https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/Object:try. "#try: Invokes the public method whose name goes as first argument just like public_send does, except that if the receiver does not respond to it the call returns nil rather than raising an exception."