# How does the &.method syntax (safe navigation operator) works in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I noticed if you type:
object &, you get the object back.
For example:

```
1.class   # => Integer
1 &.class # => Integer
'hello'.then { |x| x.equal?(x &.itself) }    # => true
[1, 2, 3] &.map(&:next)    # => [2, 3, 4]
```

I am unable to find a documentation for the syntax for `object &.method`
How does this syntax work?

Comment: Here's a link that talks about the safe navigation operator:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45825363/what-is-the-difference-between-try-and-safe-navigation-operator-in-ruby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 seperate operators here:

1. Safe navigation operator `&.` - It is safe navigation operator which was introduced in Ruby 2.3.0. It basically returns `nil` if the callee is `nil` instead of raising excecption `undefined method called for Nil class`. eg:

   ```
   a = 1
   a.next
   # => 2
   a&.next
   # => 2
   a = nil
   a.next
   # => NoMethodError (undefined method `next' for nil:NilClass)
   a&.next
   # => nil ## No exception, returns nil
   ```

   You can read about it more [here](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) and [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator)
2. Unary `&` : This operator is a little more complex. It is almost equivalent to calling `#to_proc` but not quite that. But for this discussion let us think like that. So, if you have a Proc, calling with `&` in front of it will call `#to_proc` on the Proc and convert it into a block

   ```
   multiply_by_2 = Proc.new { |x| x * 2 }
   # => #<Proc:0x00007fb4771cf560>
   # &multiply_by_2 almost equivalent to { |x| x * 2 } but is not correct syntax
   [1, 2].map(&multiply_by_2)
   # => [2, 4]
   # equivalent to  [1, 2].map { |x| x * 2 }
   ```

   But what happens if we give a symbol like :abc to `&` operator instead of a proc. It will try to call `#to_proc` on the symbol and ruby has defined `Symbol#to_proc` which roughly translates to something like this:

   ```
   def to_proc
     # this will return some block like { |x| x.send(:abc) }
     lambda { |x| x.send(self) }
   end
   ```

   So `&:abc` roughly translates to this block `{ |x| x.abc }` using the below transformation

   ```
   &:abc =====> :abc.to_proc =====> { |x| x.send(:abc) } ====> { |x| x.abc }
   ```

   So, instead of doing `[1, 2, 3].map { |x| x.next }`, you could do `[1, 2, 3].map(&:next)` as `&:next` is roughly equivalent to the block `{ |x| x.next }`.

   See [unary &](https://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/01/04/the-ampersand-operator-in-ruby#the-unary-) (which is the main source of what I have written here) for more reading.

Answer (score 1):

It's ruby syntax, & calls to_proc on the object and passes the result as a block to the method.

An explanation from the pickaxe book, programming Ruby 1.9 and 2.0

> Blocks Can Be Objects
>
> Blocks are like anonymous methods, but there’s
>   more to them than that. You can also convert a block into an object,
>   store it in variables, pass it around, and then invoke its code later.
>   Remember we said that you can think of blocks as being like an
>   implicit parameter that’s passed to a method? Well, you can also make
>   that parameter explicit. If the last parameter in a method definition
>   is prefixed with an ampersand (such as &action ), Ruby looks for a
>   code block whenever that method is called. That code block is
>   converted to an object of class Proc and assigned to the parameter.
>   You can then treat the parameter as any other variable. Here’s an
>   example where we create a Proc object in one instance method and store
>   it in an instance variable. We then invoke the proc from a second
>   instance method.

```
class ProcExample

  def pass_in_block(&action)
    @stored_proc = action
  end

  def use_proc(parameter)
    @stored_proc.call(parameter)
  end
end
```

Use it like so

```
eg = ProcExample.new
eg.pass_in_block { |param| puts "The parameter is #{param}" }
eg.use_proc(99)
```

produces:

> The parameter is 99

Comment: Also see answer from @rubyprince